# swagger API - create a perfect request

Tags: python, api, request, swagger

I have to work with an API which is a Swagger UI type, and I have the documentation of the API but seems like something is missing.

I make my request like this:

```
url = "https://something.net/some-other-part/api/devices/"
response = requests.get(url, verify=False, auth=    ("xy", "xy"))
soup = bs(response.text)
```

I get back responses with code 200, so it's OK. BUT...

The response doesn't include everything I need, altough the response class says there is a lot of information I could except to get with the response.

Without knowing the response-class of the API, can you guys tell me how can you extend the URL or the request -with paramateres for example- to get more/more specific data?

Comment: Have you tried to set the content-type header to application/json ?

Comment: It's impossible to tell without knowing which API you are calling and how this API is designed to work. You should contact the API developer and work with them to figure out why the API response does not match the API docs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only the vendor's support can address this issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 0):

Later on, I found on that the question was really not on point and solved the task on my own.